# Conditionally trigger flow based on the previous value stored in the column

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, power-automate, flow, formula

I have an OrderQuantity column in the SharePoint Online list, and I want to trigger the flow on the column value - For example, right now OrderQuantity has a value as '3', now if the user enters other than **3** any number, then only flow should trigger otherwise not.

Basically, if the column value is different than they already have, then only it should trigger.

What should be the conditional trigger? I have tried the below didn't work:

```
@not(equals(triggerBody()?['OrderQuantity ']?['Value'], triggerOutputs()?['body/OrderQuantity']))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the previous value of column directly in trigger conditions using expressions.

You have to use the "Get changes for an item or file" action to get the column value from previous version.

Then you can get all column values for particular version using REST API and compare current & previous values using "Condition".

Follow this article for detailed information: [Power Automate SharePoint Get Column Changes](https://www.sharepointsiren.com/2021/05/power-automate-sharepoint-get-column-changes/)